# SwiftUI on macOS: Make subviews in .sheet use the available width

Tags: macos, swiftui

I want to show a sheet with a title and action buttons upon clicking on a button in my macOS app. While this works, I do have an issue with the width of the containing buttons: they only use their intrinsically needed width instead of the width of their parent.

Out of the box, without providing any width values, the sheet looks like this:
[image]

I am currently hardcoding the width and applying it to the buttons – which works, but is not really sexy. The sheet then looks like this:

[image]

That's more like it. Here' my code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My View")
            Button {
                showSheet = true
            } label: {
                Text("Show Sheet…")
            }

        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SheetView(showSheet: $showSheet)
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    
    let width = CGFloat(200.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("FooBar")
            Divider()
            
            Button {
                showSheet = false
            } label: {
                Label("Foo", systemImage: "paperclip")
                    .frame(width: width)
            }
            
            Button {
                showSheet = false
            } label: {
                Label("FooBarBuzz", systemImage: "paperclip")
                    .frame(width: width)
            }
            
            Button {
                showSheet = false
            } label: {
                Label("Cancel", systemImage: "xmark")
                    .frame(width: width)
            }
        }
        .padding()

    }
}
```

**My goal though** would be to set the width of all subviews in the sheet to the subview with the biggest width – how can I do that?

Comment: You could just set the width of the surrounding VStack

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion–unfortunately this results in figure 1 with the fixed size I set the `VStack` to. My goal is that the buttons all have the same width though...